# How to read csv and take second element in line from it?

Tags: rust

> There is a csv file. There are lines in it (example: `"asd, bbb,123,456,sss\n"`).
> You need to read it and take only the second element from each line.

Please advise how to solve this problem.

```
let fname = e.path();
let _contents = fs::read_to_string(fname).expect("Should have been able to read the file");   
let _strings: Vec<&str> = _contents.split(",").collect();
```

I am reading a file in lines. And how further to select only the second element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be written as a beautiful one-liner using chained [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) methods:

```
fn main() {
    let file = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd\neee,fff,ggg,hhh";
    
    let col2: Vec<&str> = file.lines().map(|l| l.split(",").nth(2)).flatten().collect();
    
    assert_eq!(col2, vec!["ccc".to_owned(), "ggg".to_owned()]);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d6e128d02e8c0ef25738c3d8285658e)

We split the string into lines, map each line to a closure where we split the line further at every comma and select the [`nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) element (two in our case which equals the third column of the csv, because indexing starts at zero). The [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) method returns an `Option<&str>` for every line (containing the nth column if present in the line). `Option<T>` implements [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%26%27a%20Option%3CT%3E), allowing us to use the [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) method to extract the inner value from `Option`, before we use [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) to transform the iterator into a collection, `Vec<&str>` in our case.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR, [indexing syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html):

```rust
let second_element = &strings[1];
```

Or if you want to handle errors, [`Vec::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get).

---

In more detail, by using a `.collect()` you are allocating extra memory on the heap (in addition to the file contents). Unless you want to reuse the split strings later without recomputing, you should get rid of the third line and use Jonas' iterator approach.

Also note that this naive splitting is not strictly conformant to the CSV standard. Namely, you are not handling quoted strings properly:

```
foo,"bar,baz"
```

This should be two columns: `foo` and `bar,baz`; your naive splitting will erroneously produce three columns.

If you are building anything remotely serious, you should be using a library crate for parsing. See [csv on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/csv).